# SMTP certificate

Tags: java, ssl, smtp-auth, smtpd

I test [subEthaSMTP](http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/) SMTP server. Everything is OK, but I want use SSL/TLS. I read the [article](http://blog.trifork.nl/2009/11/10/securing-connections-with-tls/) about this and have a question.

I have **csr**, **crt** and **key** file, but into article used to PKCS12 , JKS, and SunX509.

Is it possible use **csr**, **crt** and **key** or how to convert it into need format.

*P.S. Sorry I am not expert in Java.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSR is a Certificate Sign Request. You should already self-sign the certificate or send to a certicate authority. If you are lost in this point, read the [certificates howto](http://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt).

Then you should have a CRT file (The CRT is a X.509 certificate in DER format) self-signed or signed by a Certificate authority, to create a PKCS#12 certificate you should:

1. Transform the DER certificate to PEM.
2. Mix PEM and KEY private key file into the PKCS#12 fileformat.

The openssl commands are [here](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html) in "Converting Using OpenSSL" section.

This stuff is not Java, It's just SSL/TLS.

Comment: Thaks a lot. I understand my mistake.